# Q: Prove $\mu^*$ is an outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f : X\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive real function. For all $A\subset X$, we define $\mu^*$ as
$$
\mu^*(A) = \sup\left\{\sum_{x \in B}{f(x) : B \subset A}\right\} 
$$

How can I show that $\mu ^*$ is an outer measure?

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be $B\subset A$ rather than $B\subseteq  A$?

Comment: Why not just say $\mu^*(A) = \sum_{x\in A}f(x)?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$ and that $A\subset B$ implies $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*(B)$. The interesting part is showing that if $B_1,B_2,\dots \subset X$, then $\mu^*\left(\bigcup_j B_j\right)\leq \sum_j \mu^*(B_j)$.

To this end, note that this equation is given by

$\sup \left\{\sum_{x\in B} f(x): B\subset \bigcup_j B_j \right\} \leq \sum_j \sup\left\{\sum_{x\in C_j}f(x) : C_j \subset B_j \right\}$.

We can rewrite the sums on the left hand side into

$\sum_{x\in B} f(x) = \sum_j \sum_{x\in B\cap B_j} f(x)$.

So you can see that this is an expression of the type that we take the supremum over on the right hand side with $C_j = B\cap B_j$. This shows that the set that we are taking the supremum over on the left hand side is contained in the one we are taking the supremum over on the right hand side. Therefore $\sum_j \mu^*(B_j)$ must be greater or equal than $\mu^*\left(\bigcup_j B_j\right)$.